# Final is not working with type alias in Python

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

Given the following code

```py
from typing import Final

ImmutableStr = Final[str]

class Test:
    s1: ImmutableStr = 'abc'
    s2: Final[str] = 'abc'

t = Test()

t.s1 = 'def'  # pass type check
t.s2 = 'def'  # error detected
```

In VsCode only report error for second case.

[image: vscode-example]

The warning of s2 is

```
Class constant name "s2" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming stylePylintC0103:invalid-name
(constant) s2: Literal['abc']
```

The error message for s2 is as the follow.  I hope s1 should report the same error.

```
Cannot assign member "s2" for type "Test"
  Member "s2" cannot be assigned through a class instance because it is a ClassVar
  "s2" is declared as Final and cannot be reassigned
    Member "__set__" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
(constant) s2: Literal['def']
```

Is the problem of VsCode or `Final` doesn't work with type alias? I am using `python 3.9.12` with Pylance.

And is there anything I can do to create an immutable type so that IDE like VsCode will report error when someone try to reassign a value to it?

Comment: What does the blue underline of `s2:` say?

Comment: `Final`, `ClassVar`, etc. are type modifiers, not types. Python typing doesn’t support attempts like `= Final[str]`. What’s wrong with using `Final` when you need it?

Comment: Just to clarify, the error message is what you want, isn't it? You are asking why don't *also* getting an error message for `s1`.

Comment: Extra info added. The reason I want to use type alias is I have a class named `InputPath` and it should always be immutable when being used. People always forget to use `Final[InputPath]` and produce strange issue. So I want to create a shortcut for it.

Comment: @link89 `Final` signals that the name it marks cannot be rebound, not that the value it points to is immutable.